# Append a string in the beginning of a line when regex matches

Tags: regex, perl, append

I have a file for example

```
Car   class    rating
ford    c        ok
merc    a        Vgood
BMW     a        Toogood
kia     c         ok
```

I want to append 'prefer' and 'dontprefer' at the beginning of the line when "a" and "c" are found respectively.

I have been doing this by seperating lines with "a" and "c" into different files and then append the required.

```
perl -ne '/a/ && print' file1.l > file2.l 

perl -ple 's/^/prefer/' file2.l
```

I have been doing this for each regex match and then combine all the files once appeneded.

So it there any other simple code to append the strings in the same file instead of shanging the files each time a regex is matched?

Sample output:

```
  .  .          Car   class    rating

dontprefer    ford    c        ok
prefer        merc    a        Vgood
prefer        BMW     a        Toogood
dontprefer    kia     c         ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
perl -pe 's/(?=.*?\sa\s)/prefer\t$1/ && print $1'
```

It will make a lookahead to check if there is an 'a' in the line and in that case replace the line with a 'prefer' in front.

Put together:

```
perl -pe 's/(?=.*?\sa\s)/prefer\t$1/g' file1.l | perl -pe 's/(?=.*?\sc\s)/dontprefer\t$1/g' > file2.l
```

Comment: Sure I have. `echo "ford    a        ok" | perl -pe 's/^((?:(?=\ta\t).)*)/prefer\t\1/ && print'` prints: `prefer  ford    a        ok`. Though twice, but this answer is a just a hint for a solution as many other... It says "try". But I simplified the regex a bit more.

Comment: You *hadn't* tried this when I posted the comment. The code in your comment puts `prefer` before *everything*

Comment: I had. I agree that it was not working right and indeed matched everything, but I realized this only now after your hint. So my test was not good as I did not test the last change I made against a negative condition. But just telling me that I did not try is not very helpful. I fixed the expression and double checked it.

Comment: well kinda, but you have written two programs that solve two parts of the problem. If your answer is *just a hint for a solution* then you must say so in your answer. It isn't a trivial task to combine those two programs to produce the output required by the OP. And you really shouldn't use `\1` in the replacement string of a Perl substitution - `$1` is correct

Comment: Well, any answer that might help the OP is an answer that is worth to write. People invest time to help others and it should not be expected only to post perfect working solutions. Although I agree they should not be wrong. So your downvote was absolutly fine. I just dont like allegations. And thanks for the info on backreferences in perl.

Comment: Could you explain to me, why I would have to use $1 instead of \0? The group I want to reference is group 0. But it actually works with $1.

Comment: @morja : not very clear about the syntax so can u tel me if i can use "car.*" in place of "a" to match "car" in "supercar" . Hope u got my question??

Comment: @unkaitha you could do the following to match car: `perl -pe 's/(?=.*?\s\w*car\s)/prefer\t$1/ && print $1'` It will match any line that has a word ending with car in it.

Comment: @morja: Perl regex groups are numbered from 1. `$0` holds the path to the Perl script being executed and is nothing to do with regular expressions. The problem with using `\1` in the replacement string like in sed is that it is a simple Perl double-quoted string, where constructs like `"\1"` mean a character with a code of (octal) 1. Perl is kind and makes it work for you when you use it in a substitution, but it's really bad syntax. See [*Warning on \1 Instead of $1*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-\1-Instead-of-$1)

Comment: @Borodin Thanxs for the explanation!

Comment: @morja: i tried using `perl -pe 's/(?=.*?\scar*\w,\s)/prefer\t$1/ && print $1'` to match a words like "carsport," . It doesnt modify the file at all. Is what i am using correct????

Comment: @unkaitha you should have a look at the regex syntax. the regex you are using does not make sence, you placed the `*` at a wrong place in `\scar*\w,\s`. This means you want to match anything that starts with ca and then any number of r followed ba a word character and a comma... Try this instead: `\scar\w*,\s`

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %prefs = (
    a => 'prefer', 
    c => 'dontprefer',
);

while (my $line = <>) {

    my $class = (split /\s+/, $line)[1];
    print $prefs{$class} if $class && $prefs{$class};
    print $line;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine for the sample input i have given but doesnt work if the position of the regex is changed. i.e. if i replace the regex "a" somewhere in column 54 in the same line its not doing the job.

Comment: I honestly don't understand your comment. If it doesn't work with your actual file content then please post said actual file content in your original post so that we can adjust the solutions accordingly.

Comment: @Moritz Bunkus: Whenever you write `split /\s+/` you almost certainly mean `split ' '`, which simply finds all contiguous non-space substrings. It is also the default if no parameters are supplied, so if you read the lines into `$_` instead, the first line of your loop can be written `my $class = (split)[1]`

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of that, and `print $line` becomes `print`. Initially I wanted to do some more regex matching for some reason, so I opted for the additional variable. I'm not golfing here, so I didn't care to change it back :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -pale 'BEGIN { %tag = ( a => "prefer", c => "dontprefer" ); } $_ = "$tag{$F[1]}\t$_" if exists $tag{$F[1]};' infile > outfile
```

Comment: @Borodin : *Insist* is a strong word and readability is subjective. My intention was to demonstrate a non-regex approach; admittedly I hadn't noticed Moritz's answer when I posted this. Your question is a little surprising - it seems that the OP wants to do some one-off file manipulation, so why not? The one-liner flags take care of a lot of the work.

Comment: +1 as this solution works fine. @Borodin, whats your problem? Having a bad day today?

Comment: @Zaid: There's a reason why people indent their code and use meaningful variable names. Writing a command-line program is an incentive to do neither of these, and here necessitates an otherwise irrelevant `BEGIN` block. Sure, if you were writing a throwaway program which you will only ever use once you can please yourself, but Stack Overflow is a place where people come for help and advice to solve their own problems, and unless those problems are *exactly* the same as this question all you are doing is making it harder for them to modify the solution to their ends. @morja: I'm fine thank you!

Comment: @Borodin : You're not obliged to like my approach and I respect that. The logic required for this problem essentially boils down to one line of code. In the spirit of TIMTOWTDI, this is what I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
perl -pe 's/(?=\S+\s+(a|(c))\s+)/($2&&"dont").($1&&"prefer\t")/e'
```

Comment: This doesnt append the sting in the begining of the line... And it just prints "prefer" when "c" is matched???  What modification am i supposed to do to print that in the begining of the line???

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'print"prefer     ".$_ if(/\s+[a]\s+/);print "dontprefer ".$_ if(/\s+[c]\s+/) ' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this may help you or not ,

> you can use SED command in linux with one line for matching and adding
>   'prefer' and 'dontprefer'at the begining of the line

Comment: I thought this was a perl question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing this in shell, so I'll offer some other solutions besides perl.

First, `awk` is sometimes a simpler programming language than perl:

```
$ awk '$2=="a"{p="prefer\t"} $2=="c"{p="dontprefer"} NR==1{p="\t"} {printf("%s\t%s\n",p,$0)}' input.txt
                Car   class    rating
dontprefer      ford    c        ok
prefer          merc    a        Vgood
prefer          BMW     a        Toogood
dontprefer      kia     c         ok
```

Next, `sed`, while cryptic, lets you condense your logic into a very tight space:

```
$ sed '1s/^/^I^I/;/ a /s/^/prefer^I^/;/ c /s/^/dontprefer^I/' input.txt
                Car   class    rating
dontprefer      ford    c        ok
prefer          merc    a        Vgood
prefer          BMW     a        Toogood
dontprefer      kia     c         ok
```

The `^I`'s are tabs.  Note that depending on your platform, your `sed` may have options that allow you to print tabs (or do other things) more efficiently.  This sed script should work everywhere.  It also suffers in that it matches `a` or `c` *anywhere* on the line, not just in the second column.  It also assume you're delimiting fields with streteches of spaces, and not tabs.  The regexp could be extended to handle these issues if they're important, but his of course works with your sample data.